# How to add "select all" functionality to ng-select in Angular 5

Tags: angular, multi-select, angular-ngselect

I found an examle which can do "select all":
https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/multiselect-checkbox

But, I get an error: `Cannot read property 'selected' of undefined.`  I am wondering why I got this error, and how to implement "select all" using ng-select in Angular 5.

Thank you

Comment: What about `selectedPeople.map(el => el.selected = true)`?

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using `ng-select` in Angular 5 limits you to using **v1.6.3** of `ng-select` (or < v2.x), but you can accomplish this using the `ng-select` header template.  I included the code below, but this is a working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-example-dyr5ss?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts) I put together as an example:

```html
<ng-select [items]="listOfItems"
            bindValue="id"
            bindLabel="name"
            [multiple]="true"
            placeholder="Select City"
            formControlName="example">

  <ng-template ng-header-tmp>

    <div>
      <button class="btn btn-link"
              (click)="onSelectAll()">Select All</button>
      <button class="btn btn-link"
              (click)="onClearAll()">Clear All</button>
    </div>

  </ng-template>

</ng-select>
```

Then in your controller you would patch the form control with an array of values mapped to only include the bound values you provided to `ng-select`, which are the `bindValue` key values.

```js
public onSelectAll() {
  const selected = this.listOfItems.map(item => item.id);
  this.form.get('example').patchValue(selected);
}

public onClearAll() {
  this.form.get('example').patchValue([]);
}
```

Comment: It worked really well, the only problem is after clicking on Select All the values get patched but the dropdown remains there only until we click outside of the dropdown. Can you please tell me how to overcome it.

Comment: You can do something like this :

IN HTML:  give id to ng select using #
<ng-select #serviceTypeDropdown name="service-type" id="service-type"
                                                bindLabel="name" placeholder="Select state" formControlName="state"
                                                [multiple]="true">

In TS: Declare view child

 @ViewChild('serviceTypeDropdown') private serviceTypeDropdown: NgSelectComponent;

and in all select method after patching the value you can simply call this function:

    this.serviceTypeDropdown.close();

Answer (score 5):

Using ng-select multi select with group by - you can add "select all" functionalities with an easy way. Here is the full example -

Demo : https://angular-mkv8vp.stackblitz.io

Code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mkv8vp?file=src/multi-checkbox-group-example.component.html

Step 1- call the method for select all group by - `this.selectAllForDropdownItems(this.people);`

Step 2- add selectedAllGroup to every items of that array for group by.

```
selectAllForDropdownItems(items: any[]) {
    let allSelect = items => {
      items.forEach(element => {
        element['selectedAllGroup'] = 'selectedAllGroup';
      });
    };

    allSelect(items);
  };
```

3. then bind  to html

- `groupBy="selectedAllGroup" [selectableGroup]="true"`

Answer (score 2):

If you do not use react forms, and wanted to use select all property, then  #getModelValue="ngModel" inside ngselect tag in html file and in *.ts file, add following code:

```
onSelectAll(select: NgModel, values, array) { 
  const selected = this.dropdownList.datas.map(item => item.id);
  select.update.emit(selected); 
}

deselectAll(select: NgModel) {
     select.update.emit([]); 
}
```